# What is the process for Google to sign apps into a user's account without the user's permission or knowledge?

Tags: google-account

I want to know about the process of how to sign to Apps in to a user's account without the user's knowledge or permission. What is the best practice for that?

I have tired many times to understand this process. I have contacted many Google Developersfor the answer but I have not received any explanation of how this works.